# Wait async tasks in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, wait, multitasking

i am newbie on android development and i would like to ask how to wait some async tasks that already running. Also when i am trying to sleep the main Thread many of them are suspended by the system. When i use an arraylist to add them and then call to each of them get() many of them never finish on time. Please give me a code example because i searching it over of three days...
Thx!!

```
for(){
  async...
  async.execute();
  arraylist.add(async);
}
...
for(arraylist.size){
    arraylist.get().get();
}
```

Comment: You mean `AsyncTask`, right?  Names are important.  And `AsyncTask` is used on the UI thread, I'd like to see more of the UI code in this example.  Something that actually compiles would be best.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? the question is not clear.

Comment: An AsyncTask tells you when it has finished by firing the `onPostExecute()` event. For your reference: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question here but the question is not clear.

If you want to check whether there is an `AsyncTask` completed or not in an arraylist, we can use `getStatus` [call](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus()) that return us a [status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html), and one of the status, luckily, is `FINISHED`, so you can check your status of any given AsyncTask.

If you want to sleep until one of the `AsyncTask` is finished, then the best approach probably involves doing something in `onPostExecute`.  When you [override it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)), you can do something to notify the main thread.  One of the ways you can do this is here:

```
public interface Callback {
  public void callBack(int id);
}
public class MainActivity implements Callback {
  private void function() {
    //do your thing
    AsyncTask task0 = new MyAsyncTask(this, 0); //implement your own asynctask here, 
    //with one of the parameters this activity so that you can get a callback. 
    //Also, optionally give in the id so that you know what index of asynctask is finished first.  
    //do the same thing for other tasks
    task1.execute(params);
  }

  public void callBack(int id) {
    arrayList.get(id).get(); //this is done
  }
```

In your `AsyncTask`, you simply override the `onPostExecute` to something like this

```
protected void onPostExecute (Result result) {
  //do your thing
  mainActivity.callBack(id);
}
```

Hope this helps.